# Reading full packet using python raw socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a raw socket for UDP packets only to do IP forwarding, using forwarding table. I am not expert in raw socket programming and my concern is how to assure that a complete UDP packet in the buffer.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1337))
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65535) #how to know that I read the complete packet not 50% or 1 and half packet 
    forwared_packet_function(packet) #here I will parse the packet change ip header and update the IP table and forward the packet
```

Is it possible to tell me how can I read one full packet by `recvfrom()`?

Answer (score -1):

I am not expert in raw socket programming too, but I have some knowledge of network.

**1st Question:**

> how to know that I read the complete packet not 50% or 1 and half packet?

Answer: You can't. It don't have "sequence number" or "acknowledgement number" like TCP.

**2nd Question:**

> Is it possible to tell me how can I read one full packet by recvfrom()?

Answer: Let try

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1337))
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65535).decode()    #decode packet
    forwared_packet_function(packet)
    print(packet)   #print packet to read
```

Comment: But in that case if the buffer doesnot contains the complete UDP packet it and I forward part of a packet or more than one packet it will lead to error?

Comment: It'll not get error in forwarding. Maybe it will get some error in other ways. It's up to what type of packet will you forward or receive. If your packet is voice, it will has some loss voice. If your packet is SETUP.exe, sure it will get some error.

Comment: How does home router do that without data loss. So its not possible to write program that what NAT does in python?

Comment: As I said it won't get any error in forwarding. But it can loss sometime because it was UDP. Please learn about QoS to minimize loss packets. And this is example of NAT in Python https://pypi.org/project/NAT-PMP/

Comment: This gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'`